# Applying multiple transformation to bitmap image(s)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am selecting one or more images from gallery and with seek bar i am specifying the range that the transformations will apply, but when i am displaying the images in GridView all images are black! my `editedImages` is `List<Bitmap> editedImages;`also i showed how i am using the intent in code below.

Code :

```
 private void applyRandomTransformations() {

    Random random = new Random();
    editedImages.clear();

    for (Uri imageUri : originalImageUris) {
        try {
            Bitmap originalImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);

            if (originalImage.getWidth() <= 0) {
                // Skip this image if the width is invalid
                continue;
            }
            // Apply rotation
            int rotationAngle = random.nextInt(MAX_ROTATION_ANGLE);
            Bitmap rotatedImage = rotateImage(originalImage, rotationAngle);

            // Apply cropping
            int cropPercentage = random.nextInt(MAX_CROP_PERCENTAGE);
            Bitmap croppedImage = cropImage(rotatedImage, cropPercentage);

            // Apply contrast adjustment
            int contrastValue = contrastSeekBar.getProgress() - (MAX_CONTRAST_VALUE / 2);
            Bitmap contrastedImage = adjustContrast(croppedImage, contrastValue);

            // Apply hue adjustment
            int hueValue = hueSeekBar.getProgress();
            Bitmap hueAdjustedImage = adjustHue(contrastedImage, hueValue);

            // Apply saturation adjustment
            int saturationValue = saturationSeekBar.getProgress() - (MAX_SATURATION_VALUE / 2);
            Bitmap finalImage = adjustSaturation(hueAdjustedImage, saturationValue);

            editedImages.add(finalImage);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

private void displayEditedImages() {
    if (!editedImages.isEmpty()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditedImagesActivity.class);

        // Convert the byte arrays to Bitmap objects
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>(editedImages);
        // Pass the edited images as an ArrayList of Bitmap objects
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("editedImages", bitmaps);


        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap image, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}

private Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap image, int cropPercentage) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int cropSize = Math.min(width, height) * cropPercentage / 100;
    int left = (width - cropSize) / 2;
    int top = (height - cropSize) / 2;
    Bitmap croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, left, top, cropSize, cropSize);
    croppedImage.setHasAlpha(true);
    return croppedImage;
}

private Bitmap adjustContrast(Bitmap image, float value) {
    Bitmap adjustedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(adjustedImage);

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.set(new float[]{
            value / 100f, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, value / 100f, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, value / 100f, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    });

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix));
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, paint);

    return adjustedImage;
}

private Bitmap adjustHue(Bitmap image, float value) {
    Bitmap adjustedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(adjustedImage);

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setRotate(0, value);
    colorMatrix.setRotate(1, value);
    colorMatrix.setRotate(2, value);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix));
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, paint);

    return adjustedImage;
}

private Bitmap adjustSaturation(Bitmap image, float value) {
    Bitmap adjustedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(adjustedImage);

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(value / 100f);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix));
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, paint);

    return adjustedImage;
}
```

**OnActivityResult**:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_PHOTOS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data.getClipData() != null) {
            int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                originalImageUris.add(imageUri);
                imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        }
        else if (data.getData() != null) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            originalImageUris.add(imageUri);
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }

        // Update the visibility of seek bars and "Generate" button
        if (!originalImageUris.isEmpty()) {
            findViewById(R.id.editOptionsLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.generateButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```